# pandas: count string criteria across down rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
  col_1
0  A
1  A:C:D
2  A:B:C:D:E
3  B:D
```

I'm trying to count each ':' to get to:

```
  col_1        count
0  A             0
1  A:C:D         2
2  A:B:C:D:E     4
3  B:D           1
```

I've tried applying a function to no avail:

```
def count_fx(df):
    return df.str.contains(':').sum()
df['count'] = df['col_1'].apply(count_fx)
```

Also,

```
df['count'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: (x.str.contains(':')).sum(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you use `apply()` here causes each element to be passed in. I.e., the DataFrame is *not* what is passed in. So you just need to change your function to

```
def count_fx(s):
    return s.count(':')
```

Then you can use what you had:

```
In [11]: df['count'] = df['col_1'].apply(count_fx)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       col_1  count
0          A      0
1      A:C:D      2
2  A:B:C:D:E      4
3        B:D      1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `str.count` method:

```
df['count'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.count(':'))

           0  count
0      A:C:D      2
1  A:B:C:D:E      4
2        B:D      1
```

Comment: Why not use the built in string method, rather than apply.  `df[0].str.count(':')`

Comment: I get an assertion error for that: `AssertionError: Level : must be same as name (None)`

Comment: @chrisb using that function is actually slower than using `apply` (see my answer).